# Vercel cant find database env variables

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel, next-auth

I'm trying to deploy an app on Vercel while using it's new Postgres DB add-on. I'm getting this build error before deployment:

```
Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-config wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Environment variable not found: POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING.
  -->  schema.prisma:8
   | 
 7 |   url               = env("POSTGRES_URL")
 8 |   directUrl         = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING")
```

These environment variables are automatically set by vercel once you connect your app to the db so I can't update these environment variables unless I disconnect the app from the db. Is anyone else running into this issue while using the following: Vercel Postgres DB, Prisma (ORM) DB Adapter, Next-Auth?

Answer (score 4):

It works if you use `.env` instead of `.env.local`

https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2557

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question about solving the issue on Vercel?

Comment: Great， this simple change of file name worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and tracked down the fact that the env variables weren't connected at all (by printing them out before the build step). I disconnected my project in Vercel from the Vercel postgres instance and then reconnected it and that seems to have done the trick!

Give it a try, it might work for you as well.

Comment: I deployed again and it solved the problem on my side

Answer (score 1):

*alengel's* answer saved my life. Thank you so much.

In your vercel project
go to **Storage** -> **Choose Project**
and press on the 3 dots on the side of your project.

Click on **Remove Project Connection**.

After removing your project click on **Connect Project** and choose your project.

Redeploy your project, and it should work.

Hopefully Vercel addresses this issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 problems:

1. .env.local isn't supported, as explained above. Note that this still isnt' called out in the docs, 7 months later.
2. Prisma can't deal with the normal setup of surrounding env variables with quote marks. I had DATABASE_URL="..." and this also fails.

Finally, Prisma really needs to make a better error message. It should print out the value read to help debug this crap.